# generate line number in data weave 2.0

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, mulesoft

My requirement is to generate a line number for every new line generated in the json message. The input message is having array inside array, i.e, parent and child array.

Input message

```
                [  
           {  
              id:"1",
              Details:[  
                 {  
                    Name:"RAM",
                    LastName:"Manohar",
                    DOB:"20-10-1990",
                    Report:[  
                       {  
                          DateOfJoin:"03-03-2019",
                          Dept:"HR",
                          BillCode:"acx-12s",
                          EffectiveDate:"03-03-2019"
                       },
                       {  
                          DateOfJoin:"03-04-2019",
                          Dept:"HR",
                          BillCode:"abc-12s",
                          EffectiveDate:"03-04-2019"
                       },
                       {  
                          Name:"Alex",
                          LastName:"Ham",
                          DOB:"20-11-1980",
                          Report:[  
                             {  
                                DateOfJoin:"03-03-2019",
                                Dept:"HR",
                                BillCode:"acx-12s",
                                EffectiveDate:"03-03-2019"
                             },
                             {  
                                DateOfJoin:"03-04-2019",
                                Dept:"HR",
                                BillCode:"abc-12s",
                                EffectiveDate:"03-04-2019"
                             }
                          ]
                       }
                    ]
                 },
                 {  
                    id:"2",
                    Details:[  
                       {  
                          Name:"Kiran",
                          LastName:"Kurella",
                          DOB:"20-10-1980",
                          Report:[  
                             {  
                                DateOfJoin:"03-03-2019",
                                Dept:"DC",
                                BillCode:"acx-12s",
                                EffectiveDate:"03-03-2019"
                             },
                             {  
                                DateOfJoin:"03-04-2019",
                                Dept:"DC",
                                BillCode:"abc-12s",
                                EffectiveDate:"03-04-2019"
                             },
                             {  
                                Name:"Sunil",
                                LastName:"Kumar",
                                DOB:"20-11-1980",
                                Report:[  
                                   {  
                                      DateOfJoin:"03-01-2019",
                                      Dept:"DC",
                                      BillCode:"acx-12s",
                                      EffectiveDate:"03-03-2019"
                                   },
                                   {  
                                      DateOfJoin:"03-04-2019",
                                      Dept:"DC",
                                      BillCode:"abc-12s",
                                      EffectiveDate:"03-04-2019"
                                   }
                                ]
                             }
                          ]
                       }
                    ]
                 }
              ]
           }
        ]
```

expected output:

```
            [{LineNumber:1,
            Dept:"HR",
            Name: "Ram"},
            {LineNumber:2,
            Dept:"HR",
            Name: "Alex"},
            {LineNumber:3,
            Dept:"HR",
            Name: "Kiran"},
            {LineNumber:4,
            Dept:"HR",
            Name: "Sunil"}]
```

Linenumber needs to be generated sequentially and irrespective of parent array or sub array. any help on this will be very appreciated. I have the logic in which i can generate the number using java function but in that case i need to set the variable value (flow variable) inside data weave which can be used in the java function to call recursively.

Comment: It's not clear how your input relates to your output. Can you please provide more specifics that relate your input data to your output data?

Comment: Also, if you already have the logic working in Java, it would helpful to provide that here as well.

Comment: @jerney I basically want to generate the linenumber number.

Comment: Vishal's answer should help. Just make sure you do `$$ + 1` because `$$` is zero-indexed.

Answer (score 0):

Use:
payload map {
  count: $$
}